# Git stash in Qt Creator fails if new files have been added to the project since last commit

Tags: git, qt-creator, git-stash

When I've just made changes to files in my project since the last commit, git stash works fine.

However, if I've also added new files to the project since the last commit, it fails with this error:

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe stash save QtCreator 2013-01-08T12:06:51
>   Cannot stash in "C:\MyProject": error: Entry 'NewFile.cpp' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
>   Cannot save the current worktree state

Why does it show this error, and is there a way stash my changes if I've added new files to the project?

**Edit**

Here is the output of `git status`

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   NewFile.cpp
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   MyFile.cpp
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   MyProject.pro.user
```

Comment: You meant to say, you have stashed the changes and now you want to pop those changes and then the error happens? :-/

Comment: No, it fails when trying to stash. See the error above. Qt Creator executes `git.exe stash save`

Comment: what does `git status` show?

Comment: I added the output of git status, see my edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Tools->Git->Stash fail in Qt Creator where Tools->Git->Undo Uncommitted Changes does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704990/why-does-tools-git-stash-fail-in-qt-creator-where-tools-git-undo-uncommitted)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Scott Chacon says,

> Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is,
>   your **modified tracked files and staged changes** — and saves it on a
>   stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time.

Since you added a new file then it doesn't know as it was not previously present, So try doing:

```
1) $ git add .
2) $ git stash
```

And see if you can able to stash those changes

Comment: it adds all the untracked/new/modified files to the index to be staged, when `git commit` is made.

Comment: This made git stash work, but now after stash pop there are files scheduled for commit that should not be in version control, like `MyProject.pro.user`.

Comment: Actually you can use git add <filename> and it would do. If you to remove the unwanted file then you can use git rm <filename>. Hope it helps..